# dojo toggle divs based on class name

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to toggle a content div in a container by clicking on the header. The site uses DOJO.

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cyuwLzkf/90/

I want this behavior for all containers of the same class. I know how to do this in jquery, but not in dojo

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
     This is my heading 
  </div>
  <div class="content hidden">
  This is the content of my message that should be hidden by default and toggled by clicking the header.
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to add the show/hide to multiple elements or how to select the content div that is inside the same container as the header that has just been clicked.
It might also be possible to add the show/hide to the container itself. If that is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed code form your fiddle:

```js
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-class", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(query, dom, domClass, on){
    
    query(".container").forEach(function(node){
 var header, content;
  header = node.getElementsByClassName("header")[0];
  content = node.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
 on(header, "click", function(){
        domClass.contains(content, "hidden")? domClass.replace(content, "show", "hidden"):         
                                         domClass.replace(content, "hidden", "show");
});
})
         
});
```

```css
.foo {
    /* add custom css */
}
.container{
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.container .header {
  background-color: grey;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<div>
    Add markup here
    <div class="container">
     <div class="header">
     This is my heading 
     </div>
      <div class="content hidden">
      This is the content of my message that should be hidden by default and toggled by clicking the header.
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <h2> Here a second container that needs same behaviour</h2>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="header">
     This is my heading 2
     </div>
      <div class="content hidden">
      And some other content that should be hidden.
      </div>
    </div>
      
</div>
```

Comment: thx, that is almost it. Only the hidden gets applied to the .header instead of the .content in the same container.

Comment: Previously I just fixed your code to properly query dom elements and assign events to it. I've updated my code with another suggestion - quering parent element.